# Rails ActiveRecord update_attributes! doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My used envs are listed below:

```
Mysql: 5.1.51-community MySQL Community Server
Rails: 2.3.5
Ruby: 1.8.7
```

There is one record i got is item, then i used the code below to update attributes,

```
item.update_attributes!(
  :a => a,
  :b => b,
  :c => c
)
```

for all those updated attributes only field a value is changed, other attributes values keep not changed, but i don't know which attributes are changed, so i updated all attributes.

During debug process, i found that field a value is changed and that's different from record item's a value, but update doesn't have any effect.

Does somebody can give me help? thank you.

Added:

Just now i trace into rails code, and found that the issue is related with rails code here:

```
    def update(attribute_names = @attributes.keys)
      quoted_attributes = attributes_with_quotes(false, false, attribute_names)
      return 0 if quoted_attributes.empty?
      connection.update(
        "UPDATE #{self.class.quoted_table_name} " +
        "SET #{quoted_comma_pair_list(connection, quoted_attributes)} " +
        "WHERE #{connection.quote_column_name(self.class.primary_key)} =     #{quote_value(id)}",
      "#{self.class.name} Update"
     )
   end
```

if i changed the field a value in db to empty, then attribute_names is an array containing field a, but the field a value in db is not empty, the attribute_names is an empty array, but @attributes is always a map containing a, b and c. confused after seeing rails code.

Comment: Not enough information is given - we need atleast the model to be able to answer this question properly.

Comment: what information else should i offer? thank u.

Comment: I don't know if it's a typo here or also used in your code, but you start with ( then end with }. If that is not the problem in your app, then you should also include the code for model Item so we can analyze properly.

Comment: @DanneManne thank u, it's a typo mistake. just now i added some notes about rails code, could you give me some further analysis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause, since the method to change the field value has errors, after changing, its original and new value are the same, so AR doesn't do update action since there is no any field is changed.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry there's not enough information in the question to go on, so this is just speculation:

Any chance you're using `attr_accessible` or `attr_protected` with this model?

Using `attr_accessible` and it doesn't include b and c, or  `attr_protected` and it includes b and c would explain the behaviour you're seeing.

If this is the case you will have to make multiple update_attribute! calls.

Comment: thank you, but i checked my code again, i don't use neither `attr_accessible` nor `attr_protected`. Just create a item record, then update. if i changed field a value in db to empty, the update will have effect, if not empty update doesn't have any effect.